# Passing props to URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using deckofcardsapi.com and I cannot pass my deck_id in props to fetch url.

Props are passing ok because when I use them in line 40 they display as normal string. And when I paste this string to variable deckId in line 23 it is giving me list of cards.

But when instead of copying string to deckId i use props.deckId there is error "TypeError: cards.cards is undefined"

On the other hand props.quantity works well.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function NewDeck(props) {
  const [deck, setDeck] = useState({ deck_id: [] });

  async function draw() {
    const result = await fetch(`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1`);
    const json = await result.json();
    setDeck(json);
  };

    useEffect(() => {
    draw();
  }, []);

  return(
    <Draw deckId={deck.deck_id} quantity={props.quantity} />
  );
}

function Draw(props) {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState({ cards: [] });
  var deckId = props.deckId;  //when i put here for egzample "l31hmefvilqe" it is working

  async function draw() {
    const result = await fetch(`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId}/draw/?count=${props.quantity}`);
    const json = await result.json();
    setCards(json);
  };

    useEffect(() => {
    draw();
  }, []);

  return(
    <ul>
      {cards.cards.map(item => (
        <li>{item.code}</li>
      ))}
      <li>deckId: {props.deckId}</li>
      <li>quantity: {props.quantity}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

export default NewDeck;
```

How to pass props.deckId to my fetch's url

I was searching for answer but with no result. This is probably my stupid mistake but i can't find it.

Thank you in adwance

Comment: Have you even console logged `props.deckId` to see if it is what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the first render of NewDeck the value of deck_id isn't set and it pass an empty array. You can fix it rendering the Draw component conditionally to the deck_id having a value . https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-margulis-olgxt In my example i set the deck_id to null and render draw only when deck_id exists.

PD: props.quantity is undefined and maybe you meant deck.remaining? Also check the draw() dependency for useEffect in the component, maybe you need to useCallback() (I0m not so sure of this because I'm still learning hooks)

Comment: Great. That was the problem.I did as you said and it's working. Quantity was defined as props from higher component. To manage with draw dependency i did like below ```function Draw(props) {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState({ cards: [] });

 useEffect(() => {
    async function draw() {
      const result = await fetch(`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${props.deckId}/draw/?count=${props.quantity}`);
      const json = await result.json();
      setCards(json);
    };
    draw();
  }, [props.deckId, props.quantity]);```